# Data Annotation MVC 4 Digits

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying to implement a field that accepts 4 digits or leave it as empty.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid 4 digit Year")]
[Display(Name = "Year")]
public int Year { get; set; }
```

When entering more than 4 numbers the error message shows up. The problem is when I enter any value which is not a numbers or a mix of numbers and non-numbers the validation error message does not show up.

I have definitely missed something. Help me out here :)

Answer (score 5):

Warren,

Try to use nullable int, so it will allow co send data through if nothing is in model, See code below for implementation

```
public class TestModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid 4 digit Year")]
    [Display(Name = "Year")]
    public int? Year { get; set; }
}
```

Updated:
My view for this code where it works is as follows

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>TestModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And my model with controller is:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new TestModel();

            return View(model);
        }
}


    public class TestModel
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid 4 digit Year")]
        [Display(Name = "Year")]
        public int? Year { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this too does not solve the problem which I have tried prior to asking for assistance. I found the culprit and will be updating the thread for the details.

Comment: We have the same view code as sample. Solving this I had to change @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year) to @Html.txtBoxFor(model => model.Year).

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is that using the @HTML.EditorFor the property int, it creates the element

```
<input type="number"/>
```

The element when inputted with values other than numbers will ignore the value and will not fire up the validation.

A solution for this is to use a field of non number type such as **@HTML.TextBoxFor**

Answer (score 0):

Change `int` to `string`. Then convert string to integer inside C#. You don't need to worry about unconvertible string, i.e `"123", "123a", "aaa"` coming from input because data validation with Regex will take care of it. Regex will throw validation error, if input value does not match the given regex pattern.

Since it is not `[Required]` field, it will take an empty string too. So valid input would be `"", "9999" or "dddd"`

**Caution**
Do not use nullable int, `int?` using that you will be inclined to use`type="number"` attribute in `input` field. In this case, if a user enters say `"123a"`, value is not convertible to a number(in js), so model binding will get `null` value and it won't trigger any validation error.

When I had `int?`, Regex did not work as it is expected.